# ffmpeg fails to Play Proxy Avid Interplay

Tags: ffmpeg

My goal is transcode this file with `ffmpeg`.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ATuPtSbZeQLexB1HBP509hInDOTyfEV8

`ffplay` fails to analize or play this file and returns:

> Invalid pixel format.

This is the simply command:

```
ffplay  -i testproxy.mxf
ffprobe -i testproxy.mxf -show_stream
```

It has been encoded by `avid Interplay` whit this targhet quality:

```
H.264 800Kbps Proxy 1080i 25
```

Maybe it's a raw file? and need same specification ahead input file?

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either Interplay doesn't write* a standard MXF or there's a limitation in ffmpeg's mxf demuxer.

But you can play the file with

```
ffplay -vcodec h264 testproxy.mxf
```

and similarly, you can transcode using

```
ffmpeg -vcodec h264 -i testproxy.mxf ...
```

*more likely, as mediainfo also fails to detect the video codec.